# Append to next line in text file using php

Tags: php, file, text, append, send

I have a php script which passes a value to a .txt file, there is no problem and it works, the only thing is I would like to append the value to the next line instead of just append the value right after another value so instead of  "valuevalue" I would like:

value

value

My script:

```
$filename4 = "EmailsFromSignUp.txt";
$content = file_get_contents($filename4);
$content .= $emailFPay;
file_put_contents($filename4, $content);
```

Comment: \n   .....................

Comment: As random user said. You add a newline, `"\r\n"` if you want it to work in windows notepad, `"\n"` if you use a proper text editor. :-)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try

```
$content .= PHP_EOL . $emailFPay;
```

Comment: You are quite welcome, feel free to accept as the answer if you like ;-)

Answer (score 1):

```
$f = fopen("EmailsFromSignUp.txt", "a+");
fputs($f, "\n" . $emailFPay);
fclose($f);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$filename4 = "EmailsFromSignUp.txt";
$content = file_get_contents($filename4);
$content .= "\r\n" . $emailFPay;
file_put_contents($filename4, $content);
```