# save info in a specific way into txt file with php

Tags: php, string, file

I'm working with a txt file and PHP and I need to save data into this txt file, save and open the file is not a problem with file_get_contents and file_put_contents but I have a doubt please help me if you can:

I present the info in this order:

```
issue info 1
issue info 2
issue info 3
```

as you can see I show to the user the issues in different lines, but that works when I display that info in the browser but if I open the txt file it shows this:

```
issue info 1issue info 2issue info3
```

all in the same line, how can I do in order to save the info into the txt file with the order:

```
issue info 1
issue info 2
issue info 3
```

thanks in avance, this is my code by the moment:

```
$filename = "C:/Users/usuario/Videos/Desktop/prueba.txt";
if(file_exists($filename)) {
$filestring = file_get_contents($filename, NULL, NULL);

$convert = explode("\n", $filestring);

for ($i=0;$i<count($convert);$i++)  
{
      echo $convert[$i]. "</br>";  
    }

    echo "</br>";
    $filestring.= "issue 1"."</br>";
    file_put_contents($filename, $filestring);
    echo "</br>";

}
else{
    die("ese file no existe");
}
```

Comment: You're just 10 minutes late: http://stackoverflow.com/q/29780379/3933332 ...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why not just add a new line characters to your strings (before and after the BR tags)?

```
"\r\n"
```

This way, you'll get the line breaks in HTML and in text files.

Also, make sure to double-quote the newline characters, or else PHP will not evaluate them properly.

Answer (score 1):

Use `\n` in your code, see this example:

```
<?php

$string = '';

for($i = 1; $i <= 3; $i++) {
    $string .= 'issue info ' . $i . "\n";
}   

file_put_contents('11.txt', $string);

?>
```

Output:

```
issue info1
issue info2
issue info3
```

Comment: I upvoted your answers, thanks for he help it worked using "\r\n"

Comment: @PabloTobar you're welcome and good luck with your work ;-)